# Using @IndexingDependency derivedFrom and a property bridge

Tags: hibernate-search, hibernate-search-6

I would like to use hibernate search's `@IndexingDependency` with a `PropertyBridge` but I can't seem to make it work.

I get this error :

```
Hibernate ORM mapping: type 'com.something.Person': path '.currentStatus': 
  failures: 
    - HSEARCH700020: Unable to find the inverse side of the association on type
    'com.something.Person' at path '.currentStatus<no value extractors>'. Hibernate Search
    needs this information in order to reindex 'com.something.Person' when
    'com.something.Status' is modified. You can solve this error by defining the inverse
    side of this association,  either with annotations specific to your integration
    (@OneToMany(mappedBy = ...) in Hibernate ORM)  or with the  Hibernate Search 
    @AssociationInverseSide annotation. Alternatively, if you do not need to reindex 
    'com.something.Person' when 'com.something.Status' is modified, you can disable 
     automatic reindexing with @IndexingDependency(reindexOnUpdate = ReindexOnUpdate.SHALLOW)
```

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong or if what I'm trying to do isn't possible. Thank for the help.

Here are the files involved.

**Person.class**

```
@Entity
@Table
@Indexed
public class Person {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
    private Set<Status> status = new HashSet<>();

    @Transient
    @StatusBinding(fieldName = "currentStatus")
    @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "status")))
    public Status getCurrentStatus() {
        return this.status.stream()
            .filter(it -> it.getDate().isAfter(LocalDate.now()))
            .max(Comparator.comparing(Status::getDate))
            .orElse(null);
    }
}
```

**StatusBinding.class**

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@PropertyMapping(processor = @PropertyMappingAnnotationProcessorRef(type = StatusBinding.Processor.class))
@Documented
public @interface StatusBinding {

    String fieldName() default "";

    class Processor implements PropertyMappingAnnotationProcessor<StatusBinding> {
        @Override
        public void process(PropertyMappingStep mapping, StatusBindingannotation, PropertyMappingAnnotationProcessorContext context) {
            StatusBinderbinder = new StatusBinder();
            if (!annotation.fieldName().isBlank()) binder.setFieldName(annotation.fieldName());
            mapping.binder(binder);
        }
    }
}
```

**StatusBinder.class**

```
public class StatusBinder implements PropertyBinder {
    @Setter private String fieldName = "mainStatus";

    @Override
    public void bind(PropertyBindingContext context) {
        context.dependencies()
            .use("status")
            .use("date")
            .use("note");

        IndexSchemaObjectField mainStatusField = context.indexSchemaElement().objectField(this.fieldName);

        context.bridge(Status.class, new StatusBridge(
                mainStatusField.toReference(),
                mainStatusField.field("status", context.typeFactory().asString()).toReference(),
                mainStatusField.field("date", context.typeFactory().asLocalDate()).toReference(),
                mainStatusField.field("note", context.typeFactory().asString()).toReference()
        ));
    }

    private static class StatusBrige implements PropertyBridge<Status> {
        private final IndexObjectFieldReference mainStatusField;
        private final IndexFieldReference<String> statusField;
        private final IndexFieldReference<LocalDate> dateField;
        private final IndexFieldReference<String> noteField;

        public StatusBrige(
                IndexObjectFieldReference mainStatusField,
                IndexFieldReference<String> statusField,
                IndexFieldReference<LocalDate> dateField,
                IndexFieldReference<String> noteField
        ) {
            this.mainStatusField = mainStatusField;
            this.statusField = statusField;
            this.dateField = dateField;
            this.noteField = noteField;
        }

        @Override
        public void write(DocumentElement target, Status mainStatus, PropertyBridgeWriteContext context) {
            DocumentElement statutElement = target.addObject(this.mainStatusField);
            statutElement.addValue(this.statusField, mainStatus.getStatus);
            statutElement.addValue(this.dateField, mainStatus.getDate());
            statutElement.addValue(this.noteField, mainStatus.getNote());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Problem

When a `Status` entity is modified, Hibernate Search doesn't know how to retrieve the corresponding `Person` having that `Status` as its `currentStatus`.

## Solution

Assuming the `currentStatus` is always contained in `status`, and since `Status.patient` is the inverse side of the `Person.status` association, you  should only need to add this:

```java
    @Transient
    @StatusBinding(fieldName = "currentStatus")
    @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "status")))
    // ADD THIS ANNOTATION
    @AssociationInverseSide(
            inversePath = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "patient"))
    )
    public Status getCurrentStatus() {
       // ...
    }
```

## Why?

I'll try to explain this, but it's a bit complex, so bear with me.

Derived properties and the inverse side of associations are related concepts: they share the common purpose of allowing Hibernate Search to perform automatic reindexing.

However, they are still separate concepts, and Hibernate Search is not able to infer one from the other.

With [`@IndexingDependency(derivedFrom)`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-derivedfrom), you are defining what the computation of `currentStatus` depends on:

```java
    @IndexingDependency(derivedFrom = @ObjectPath(@PropertyValue(propertyName = "status")))
    public Status getCurrentStatus() {
```

This tells Hibernate Search that `currentStatus` will change whenever the `status` property changes. With that information, Hibernate Search is able to determine that whenever you call `person.getStatus().remove(...)` or `person.getStatus().add(...)` (for example), your `Person` entity needs reindexing, because `currentStatus` is indexed, and it probably changed.

In your custom binder, you're also [defining dependencies](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-bridge-bridgedelement-dependencies):

```java
        context.dependencies()
            .use("status")
            .use("date")
            .use("note");
```

This tells Hibernate Search that whenever the `status`, `date`, and `note` properties of a `Status` entity change, the `Person` having that `Status` as its `currentStatus` will need reindexing.

However... what Hibernate Search doesn't know is how to retrieve the person having that `Status` as its `currentStatus`.

It may know how to retrieve all persons having that `Status` in their `status` set, but that's a different thing, isn't it? Hibernate Search doesn't know that `currentStatus` is actually one of the elements contained in the `status` property. For all it knows, `getCurrentStatus()` could very well be doing this: `status.iterator().next().getParentStatus()`. Then the current status wouldn't be included in `Person#status`, and it's unclear if `myStatus.getPatient()` could return a `Person` whose `currentStatus` is `myStatus`.

So you need to tell Hibernate Search explicitly: "from a given `Status myStatus`, if you retrieve the value of `myStatus.getPatient()`, you get the `Person` whose `currentStatus` property may point back to `myStatus`". That's exactly what [`@AssociationInverseSide`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapper-orm-reindexing-associationinverseside) is for.

Comment: Works perfectly and I understand why,! Thanks a lot !